# set! Unbound identifier in module ERROR in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I try to write a function that returns a random number between the first and the second argument.

(random-between 40 80)

Should give a random number between 40 and 80. Here is the code:

```
(define (random-between x y)
   ((set! result (random y))
        (if (> result x)
            result
            (random-between x y))))
```

I suppose when the function runs recursively the second time, the random function creates a new *result* who is again tested and if it is above x it is output as the final result.

This is the first time I use "set!" and it gives me this error:

*set!: unbound identifier in module in: result*

The other similar questions didn't help me find a solution.

Comment: `((set! result (random y)) ...)` is nonsensical. Why not just use `let`?

Comment: My keyboard is broken and I can't type "L" without using telekinesis to change the bits in the RAM. Or maybe we all start somewhere.

Comment: I dont know what you saying, but a double parenthesis is generally a place of concern unless it evaluates to a procedure. In your case, `set!` will never do that.

Comment: I didn't knew the difference between set and let until 1 hour ago.

Comment: We all learn, but learning the hard way, sticks forever :D

Comment: @leppie, FWIW, this kind of confusion is common among newbies who miss the fact that `int x = E` and `x = E` in mainstream languages are two very different things, so they tend to blindly translate `=` to `set!`.  (Or people who come from Ruby/Coffescript where the language itself is confused and therefore confusing.)

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my own question as I would have wished for others to answer it. Not snarky answers or book recommendations.

Yes, you need to use *let* which has this syntax:

```
(let ([id value]) body-which-is-evaluated-after)
```

And this is the code that has no recursion for speed efficiency.

```
(define (random-between x y)
    (let ([result (- y x)]) 
         (+ (random result) x)))
```

Comment: I was not trying to be snarky. But I was trying to let you think about the solution instead. I am glad you took the hint I supplied and did it :D +1

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry I might have overreacted.

Comment: No problem, I had similar reactions when learning Scheme. That is the problem with a language that is over 40 years old :D